# How can I set up my environment for the upcoming Marlowe Pioneer Program?

Tags: marlowe-pioneer-program

I'm interested in getting ready for the upcoming Marlowe Pioneer Program. I know that for programmers one interesting flavor around all Marlowe components is to use the cli. What do I need to get early access to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So exploring the [repo](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano) for the marlowe DSL lang. It is better to get Nix rather than installing ghc, stack,cabal, etc... locally. Nix contains everything we need.

To install Nix you can follow this guide [HERE](https://plutus-community.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#Environment/Build/Ubuntu/) (I tried the single-user on Ubuntu 20.04).

Then we clone the [marlowe-cardano](https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano) repo and just run a nix-shell

```
$ git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/marlowe-cardano
$ cd marlowe-cardano
$ nix-shell
```

this takes several minutes and will get us every dependency for the Marlowe language and the cli.

```
[nix-shell:~/marlowe-cardano]$ nix-env --version
nix-env (Nix) 2.8.1
[nix-shell:~/marlowe-cardano]$ marlowe-cli --version
marlowe-cli 0.0.4.0
```

and we are good to go!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know the intended environment at the moment as  no details have been provided, but you can't go wrong having an Ubuntu workstation to work with. This will let you install/setup any needed code and packages, and you can easily run CLI and HTTP interfaces if they are needed.

Marlowe previously (still?) had a website with a drag-drop 'blocky' interface along with a CLI interface on the website. The course might offer something similar to this rather than each user needing to set up a local environment, in order to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

The following two videos made by Plutus Pioneers gives us a good start.
https://youtu.be/mnfItts6VbU
https://youtu.be/g2F9raiGp_s

I didn't clone the Plutus repository as shown in the videos because I don't know if we will need that but I did jump around the videos and followed the directions for installing WSL, VSCode, Cabal, and Nix.

Haskell was installed at the linux terminal window with the following command

```
sudo apt install ghc
```

Tomorrow I am going to try and install the Cardano-CLI and the Marlow_CLI which I understand from [this document](https://8848114.fs1.hubspotusercontent-na1.net/hubfs/8848114/Marlowe/Documents/Marlowe%20Pioneers%20pre-read.pdf?utm_medium=email&_hsmi=213306802&_hsenc=p2ANqtz-9men7V0DsjltIkAFTNbmhwQG5QMQYDjuVD8IZY3hyj2lPYaxzP3QmkQoGE-apJq0YsMe4zI1q0gGQcESRocODWs6Wd6g&utm_content=213306802&utm_source=hs_email) will be necessary.