# MacOS nix-shell (fail) after cd marlowe-cardano

Tags: marlowe-pioneer-program

I followed the instructions for MacOS setup from here:
[How can I set up my environment for the upcoming Marlowe Pioneer Program?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/8146/how-can-i-set-up-my-environment-for-the-upcoming-marlowe-pioneer-program)

... which worked well up until
cd marlowe-cardano
$ nix-shell

MacOS version: 12.3.1 Monterey.

... nix-shell worked for a while, installing until it failed:

Preprocessing library for plutus-ledger-constraints-0.1.0.0..
Building library for plutus-ledger-constraints-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 4] Compiling Ledger.Constraints.TxConstraints ( src/Ledger/Constraints/TxConstraints.hs, dist/build/Ledger/Constraints/TxConstraints.o, dist/build/Ledger/Constraints/TxConstraints.dyn_o )
[2 of 4] Compiling Ledger.Constraints.OnChain ( src/Ledger/Constraints/OnChain.hs, dist/build/Ledger/Constraints/OnChain.o, dist/build/Ledger/Constraints/OnChain.dyn_o )
[3 of 4] Compiling Ledger.Constraints.OffChain ( src/Ledger/Constraints/OffChain.hs, dist/build/Ledger/Constraints/OffChain.o, dist/build/Ledger/Constraints/OffChain.dyn_o )
: error:
: dlopen(/nix/store/7zv7cy150qlqrhn8jx4hwchmnj16c9fa-cardano-wallet-core-lib-cardano-wallet-core-2022.1.18-config/lib/links/libHSappar-0.1.8-KYad8eEAlRI90NAZOjuGzF-ghc8.10.4.20210212.dylib, 0x0005): cannot dlopen until fork() handlers have completed
[107 of 114] Compiling UnliftIO.Compat  ( src/UnliftIO/Compat.hs, dist/build/UnliftIO/Compat.o, dist/build/UnliftIO/Compat.dyn_o )
[108 of 114] Compiling Cardano.DB.Sqlite ( src/Cardano/DB/Sqlite.hs, dist/build/Cardano/DB/Sqlite.o, dist/build/Cardano/DB/Sqlite.dyn_o )
error: builder for '/nix/store/f4ybcf3n7hk2yfn375ikgz9r4l37nfa3-cardano-wallet-core-lib-cardano-wallet-core-2022.1.18.drv' failed with exit code 1;
last 10 log lines:
> [ 99 of 114] Compiling Data.Vector.Shuffle ( src/Data/Vector/Shuffle.hs, dist/build/Data/Vector/Shuffle.o, dist/build/Data/Vector/Shuffle.dyn_o )
> [101 of 114] Compiling Network.Wai.Middleware.Logging ( src/Network/Wai/Middleware/Logging.hs, dist/build/Network/Wai/Middleware/Logging.o, dist/build/Network/Wai/Middleware/Logging.dyn_o )
> [102 of 114] Compiling Network.Wai.Middleware.ServerError ( src/Network/Wai/Middleware/ServerError.hs, dist/build/Network/Wai/Middleware/ServerError.o, dist/build/Network/Wai/Middleware/ServerError.dyn_o )
> [105 of 114] Compiling Paths_cardano_wallet_core ( dist/build/autogen/Paths_cardano_wallet_core.hs, dist/build/Paths_cardano_wallet_core.o, dist/build/Paths_cardano_wallet_core.dyn_o )
> [106 of 114] Compiling Cardano.Wallet.Version ( src/Cardano/Wallet/Version.hs, dist/build/Cardano/Wallet/Version.o, dist/build/Cardano/Wallet/Version.dyn_o )
>
> : error:
>     : dlopen(/nix/store/7zv7cy150qlqrhn8jx4hwchmnj16c9fa-cardano-wallet-core-lib-cardano-wallet-core-2022.1.18-config/lib/links/libHSappar-0.1.8-KYad8eEAlRI90NAZOjuGzF-ghc8.10.4.20210212.dylib, 0x0005): cannot dlopen until fork() handlers have completed
> [107 of 114] Compiling UnliftIO.Compat  ( src/UnliftIO/Compat.hs, dist/build/UnliftIO/Compat.o, dist/build/UnliftIO/Compat.dyn_o )
> [108 of 114] Compiling Cardano.DB.Sqlite ( src/Cardano/DB/Sqlite.hs, dist/build/Cardano/DB/Sqlite.o, dist/build/Cardano/DB/Sqlite.dyn_o )
For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/f4ybcf3n7hk2yfn375ikgz9r4l37nfa3-cardano-wallet-core-lib-cardano-wallet-core-2022.1.18.drv'.
error: 1 dependencies of derivation '/nix/store/dvcxsznm7y2vlylprmgmxaxkrz127ng3-cardano-wallet-exe-cardano-wallet-2022.1.18.drv' failed to build
error: build of '/nix/store/0qc5jy1gq7wvfrh8cgk8simha4kcy1yw-marlowe-play-spago.drv', '/nix/store/1n6k5x1w9anmdyy8sk91jy3ccgm05vf1-haskell-language-server-wrapper.drv', '/nix/store/2nh1qzgav72nhqx3z1z9vpslykc91ql4-marlowe-run-server.drv', '/nix/store/2vwdv3q4y9x9hizcc6nrzzaxbkv9f8pc-fix-dhall.drv', '/nix/store/2xwv0nk72cjxy6hvknnvkml99il3av0p-fix-stylish-haskell.drv', '/nix/store/3713lqy701bvfk5ajxypq64jsygfzmsb-start-dashboard-server.drv', '/nix/store/3cn5w7pfgxg6l22aqvd95246v3yhhjr7-marlowe-run-generate-purs.drv', '/nix/store/5cxhfxjy2sil7nax62mckchg1xc5idk9-fix-purs-tidy.drv', '/nix/store/5zszwp9j729xijzvwcnphy26gnjifl44-updateMaterialized.drv', '/nix/store/65l907v2srfpqh1vi208mxac13l9d4x0-marlowe-run-test.drv', '/nix/store/693hfzb5rlpfkf23zgxcg57fhyz9k89a-start-chain-index.drv', '/nix/store/8lvv31qg971507d244ipfci9sjncm2q3-start-cardano-node.drv', '/nix/store/9kxgfphjxpflks2as3rv4vw4n2vsqy49-start-marlowe-run.drv', '/nix/store/dvcxsznm7y2vlylprmgmxaxkrz127ng3-cardano-wallet-exe-cardano-wallet-2022.1.18.drv', '/nix/store/gf3wry42mkylrln6j630x5cz95ckfgpi-marlowe-playground-generate-purs.drv', '/nix/store/hbrm722bkf986l20cmlsh2jdqwnalw37-marlowe-run-spago.drv', '/nix/store/hmww1licvw5ymk8vvf69a5376ly1s205-haskell-language-server-exe-haskell-language-server-1.3.0.0.drv', '/nix/store/hqma6a8a48g0lwy811b89xh93jz9dcnn-ghc-shell-for-packages-ghc-8.10.4.20210212-env.drv', '/nix/store/hvz6yfsj3azapdl4r3p92nj24rz0wrnx-pre-commit-config.json.drv', '/nix/store/i45s1bvam4xpg1ssz1kprizkzzhm7kzi-marlowe-playground-server.drv', '/nix/store/ill6y3fxqg8j75qhq4qyrbwa2p1j65a2-generate-purescript.drv', '/nix/store/kiq89kgza8shhc3qx7mxdl5lhkj7qk1y-fix-prettier.drv', '/nix/store/kw40pqdaq4vibc81c8gylkx3ikwwlmk3-blockfrost-client-lib-blockfrost-client-0.3.1.0.drv', '/nix/store/lwapgnmc48inbjdsximapbm9k9mfbc4n-marlowe-cli-exe-marlowe-cli-0.0.4.0.drv', '/nix/store/vbv7f25mjlprckimfvmf2v881l0afcrh-start-marlowe-pab.drv', '/nix/store/x006fz3vjkykqf1m96jzh54nj22zghf4-start-cardano-wallet.drv', '/nix/store/y1n8l4jznbm0q4xrlgbhly6lnd9im60s-update-client-deps.drv', '/nix/store/z6xqdvz6grjpxdkkp3k2g47zyd2hw8hq-python3-3.9.6-env.drv', '/nix/store/z9bsag150pgrskwj3pza4kbfcd53djk1-marlowe-exe-marlowe-pab-0.1.0.0.drv', '/nix/store/zbdiqa6snqkrjmdz270dggac1sd5427l-plutus-chain-index-exe-plutus-chain-index-0.1.0.0.drv' failed

... so it looks like it got hung up when trying to do:
Preprocessing library for plutus-ledger-constraints-0.1.0.0

Note i tried entering nix shell after marlowe install... and there's an "segmentation fault" error:

nix-shell marlowe-cardano/shell.nix
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for cabal-install entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for haskell-project entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for haskell-project entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
zsh: segmentation fault  nix-shell marlowe-cardano/shell.nix

Answer (score 1):

Closing the loop on this. I was able to install Daedalus locally, and open a Marlowe terminal from the menu. This is much simpler, and it seems to work just fine. :) Advise using the CLI from Daedalus as the preferred method of local development, at least on a Mac.

Comment: Hi Aaron, you can mark this one or any other answer as correct to let everybody know your question has been answered. Cheers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mac users have to configure their nix setup a little differently than other environments. You might need to update your nix.conf file located in `/etc/nix/nix.conf`.

You can find the specific instructions for Mac users here: https://plutus-community.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#Environment/Build/MacOS/

And Mac M1 users here: https://plutus-community.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#Environment/Build/Mac_M1/

After updating your nix config, make sure to restart your machine and try again.

Comment: Thanks... I followed the Mac instructions precisely, and a lot worked. However, it looked like it all messed up here: Preprocessing library for plutus-ledger-constraints-0.1.0.0..
Building library for plutus-ledger-constraints-0.1.0.0.. this part failed. Hence, it doesn't appear all the tools installed/built.

Comment: Going to try Nix install directions... https://nixos.org/download.html#nix-install-macos

Comment: Closing the loop on this. I was able to install Daedalus locally, and open a Marlowe terminal from the menu. This is much simpler, and it seems to work just fine. :)